# Prevent white space from wrapping together with word

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap

The easiest way to describe my problem is by example: http://jsfiddle.net/trSwG/1/

The **first paragraph** is great, it's displayed exactly how I want it to. No matter how much white-space is added to the first line, it's truncated and isn't wrapped to the second line.

The **second paragraph** is where the problem lies. The space preceding the word "case" should not be included on this line, I want it to stay on the line above and act like how it does in the first paragraph.

The **third paragraph** is also fine, this is just to show that I want white-space to be preserved. It's also worth noting I don't want words broken (word-break: break-all).

I've attached a screenshot below, just in case it's rendering differently on your browsers. I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m:

[image: example]

You'll notice I'm using the [lettering.js plugin](http://letteringjs.com/) to wrap every character inside a span, this is required for a feature we're developing.

**What I've learnt so far:**

It seems the spans are causing the problem, if you remove lettering call:

```
//$('p').lettering();
```

it all works as I need it. Somehow the spans are acting differently than normal text.

**Update:** The html itself cannot be manually edited either. It's created by a Flash content management tool and saved together with other properties as XML. There are thousands of these xml documents. The server has a chance to process the XML before it's sent as HTML to the front end, so any solution involving changing the html would need to be scripted.

Comment: so what do you want? Disable text wrap for the first line only?

Comment: In this simplified example, the main thing is that I don't want the word "case" in the second paragraph to be indented by a single space. The space character should, in my opinion, stay on the first line, like in the first paragraph. A better example might be: http://jsfiddle.net/trSwG/3/. Notice the text is not justified neatly to the left.

Comment: what about white-space: pre-line;  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, pre-line doesn't preserve white-space. It breaks paragraph 3.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can apply for all paragraphs the **white-space: pre-line;** style, while for the last one **white-space: pre-wrap;** http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/trSwG/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a Chrome bug in version 28: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246127

It's fixed in the currently beta version 29, only a matter of time before it gets pushed to the public build.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

What about simply in CSS:

```
p {
    width: 160px;
    white-space: pre-line;    
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}
p:last-child {
    white-space: pre-wrap;    
}
```

Comment: apologies for not mentioning something so critical - editing the html manually is not an option. I've updated the question as to why.

Comment: then you can use JavaScript replace() Method and replace white space after first sentence with a linebreak

Comment: This solution is too specific to this single case. The paragraphs could be in any order. Here's a more complex example: http://jsfiddle.net/trSwG/9/. I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/trSwG/8/ (commented out lettering.js).

Comment: they look identical on my Google Chrome: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/QxuDvLT.png) [same with P, same with PRE]
Is that an issue on a specific browser?

Comment: Interesting. What's your Chrome version?

Comment: 29.0.1547.22 beta-m [Chrome Beta Channel]

Comment: hmm strange. It does work perfectly on IE8-10, Safari latest and Firefox latest.

Comment: Yep, it was a Chrome bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246127